# How can I install these pre-hung doors?

Tags: doors, trim, jamb

OK so I got about 20 interior prehung 6-panel doors with trim from Lowe's for $50 a piece.  I was buying a lot of stuff they wanted to get rid of.  Now putting up 8 news doors in a house.  All of the jambs are 4 inches...

Well when I bought the doors they told me that they were fine for 2x4 construction. Didn't tell me that it would be 2x4 with 1/4 inch drywall. The problem is that I have 1/2" drywall, making the jamb a 1/2 inch too wide.

Are the 4 inch jambs common and what is the easiest way to add the outer strip?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Are you not putting up drywall?

Comment: Drywall is already up and we have a couple of doors up.  Jamb is 4 inches.  2x4 - is 3.5 inches wide.  Then 1/2 inch drywall on each side.  Leaves me 1/2 inch gap on non-hinge side.

Comment: Can you center the door so there's 1/4" on each side and try to make the casing fit?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - I could on some but others will open 180 degrees and I am afraid of the hinges hitting trim if that makes sense.  Also I would have to fill that 1/4 inch gap or my trim will be slanted in towards the door.

Comment: Where they special order or clearance? I have installed many prehung doors from lowes.  The instock door jamps are always 4 5/8 wide.

Comment: Depending on the size they are normally $55-$59  adding that 1/2 strip will be a pain and probably not end up looking right.  Return them for something that fits, not worth saving a couple bucks

Comment: Are these standard split jamb doors where you pull a few wood blocks and it comes apart? In that case, are you sure it's only 4" and not 4" at it's smallest width?

Comment: @JustinK - these are solid and nice.  About 160 per door new.

Comment: @BMitch - that was my first reaction...  but then nothing.  I did call Lowe's and they told me I got wrong info and they were for 2x3 (real 2x3s)...  They knocked another 300 off the order so whatever.  The doors look too good to take back so it is either fix with jamb extender as bib pointed out, buy new jambs, or come up with something else.

Comment: You could always build your own jambs, and then hang the door in that. If there is already a jamb in place, it's probably easier simply to hang the door in place anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason that you can't make *jamb extenders* these are routinely used in prehung windows. The casings and whatever you use to bridge the gap to the jamb are just trim and have no structural component.

The trick is to avoid using the exact same thickness. When two pieces are meeting in a plane, it is best to have a slight *reveal*, an offset (usually between 1/8 and 3/16 inch). This way you have an intended step, not an almost exact match (that is never quite exact).

[image: jamb extender]

You can glue the edge of the extender to the edge of the jamb (maintaining the reveal) and pin the face of the extender to the underlying stud.

Most stock prehung doors use jambs that are 4 9/16 inches, wide enough for 2x4 framing (1.5x3.5 actually) and two 1/2 inch drywall faces.

Comment: This is exactly what we did in my house where we ran into this problem. 90% of carpentry is hiding mistakes. Just use some poplar and trim nails to extend the jamb, use some wood filler and sand it lightly, and by the time you've primed and painted no one will ever notice.